# I want to generate an array of columns names to assign it as attributes of my class .. any ideas?

Tags: php, mysql

Here is my array :

```
protected static $db_fields = array('id', 'username', 'password');
```

Here is how I use it for:

```
protected function attributes(){
    $attributes = array();
    foreach(static::$db_fields as $field){
        $attributes[$field] = $this->$field;
    }
    return $attributes;
}
```

Here is how I use attributes :

```
protected function create(){
    global $database;
    $attributes = $this->sanitized_attributes();

    $sql = "INSERT INTO " . static::$table_name . " (";
    $sql .= join(", ", array_keys($attributes));
    $sql .= ") VALUES ('";
    $sql .= join("', '", array_values($attributes));
    $sql .= "')";

    if($database->query($sql)){
        $this->id = $database->inserted_id();
        return TRUE;
    }else{
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

All I need to do is to generate that db_fields array from the database directly not assigning it manually like what I did. I played around with 'SHOW COLUMNS FROM' table name, but without any luck.

Show columns :

```
function attributes(){
    global $database;
    $attributes = array();
    $sql = "SHOW COLUMNS FROM " . static::$table_name;
    $result = $database->query($sql);
    $db_fields = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

    for($i = 0; $i < mysql_num_rows($result); $i++){
        while ($db_fields = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
          $attributes[] = $db_fields['Field'];
        }
    }

    return $attributes;
}
```

My final approach should be an array like:

```
$db_fields = ('column1_name', 'column2_name', 'column3_name')
```

The result of my current "SHOW COLUMNS" play around is that it makes the value of username: username, password: password ... just as the column's name.

I believe it's how I assign these columns names to my array is the problem. So what is the right query to make such an array?

Finall I solved it:

```
protected static $db_fields;

function __construct(){
    self::generate_attributes();
}

protected static function generate_attributes(){
    $sql = "SHOW COLUMNS FROM admins";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    $rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

    for($i = 0; $i < mysql_num_rows($result); $i++){
        while ($rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
          self::$db_fields[] = $rows['Field'];
        }
    }
    return self::$db_fields;
}
protected function attributes(){
    $attributes = array();
    foreach(static::$db_fields as $field){
        $attributes[$field] = $this->$field;
    }
    return $attributes;
}
```

Thank you all for trying to help.

Comment: Show us the query you tried with `SHOW COLUMNS FROM`

Comment: add it to the question details, not in a comment.

Answer (score 1):

How about trying

```
SELECT `column_name` FROM `information_schema`.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'yourtable';
```

Your db user wil require read access on the information_schema.

If required, you can also use GROUP_CONCAT to create a comma separated string.

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(c.column_name) FROM `information_schema`.COLUMNS c WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'yourtable';
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, I solve it finally. I posted the solution on the post.

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = "SELECT * from myTable LIMIT 1";
if ($result = mysqli_query($link, $query)) {
$finfo = mysqli_fetch_fields($result);

foreach ($finfo as $val) {
   print_r($val);
}
mysqli_free_result($result);
}
```

Comment: Seems a little overkill when `SHOW COLUMNS` should work just fine.

Comment: Yes I agree, but this is just one of many possible solutions. Since OP mentioned they could not get `SHOW COLUMNS` to work

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
function attributes(){
    global $database;
    $attributes = array();
    $sql = "SELECT column1_name,column2_name,column3_name FROM " . static::$table_name;//your columns
    $result = $database->query($sql);
    $db_fields = array('column1_name', 'column2_name', 'column3_name') ;
    $i=0;
    if(mysql_num_rows($result)){
        while ($rows = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
           for($j=0;$j<count($db_fields);$j++)
           {
               $attributes[$i][$db_fields[$j]] = $rows[$j] ;
           }
           $i++;
        }
    }
    return $attributes;
}
```

Comment: Nope, what I need to approach is an array like $db_fields = ('column1_name', 'column2_name', 'column3_name')

Comment: Thank you for your help, I solve it finally. I posted the solution on the post.

Answer (score 0):

Try these
use your table name and schema to get all details regarding to columns.

```
SELECT `column_name`  FROM `information_schema`.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'table_name' AND TABLE_SCHEMA = 'database_name'
```

you can use `*` instead of `column_name`

check inaformation_schema table it has lot much to know